# Posts not displaying properly after if else loop put in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

2 problems:

1) the Recent Posts function in my view file (for the single post page) no longer shows posts.
2) On the articles page which shows all of the posts, the posts with no slug do not work. when I click on the post, it redirects to /articles. Only posts with a slug work.

I have 2 kinds of URLs for my posts: slug and url.  The difference?  URL is longer.  Slug is shorter and used for SEO purposes.  Why not use just slug?  Because for some posts, I don't want to waste time creating a slug.  The data in the slug column for those posts is blank/empty.  The generated url is fine.  For other posts, I want a slug made.

Here is my controller code for posts.

Old version:

```
public function viewpost($url,$slug){
if ( empty($slug) ) {
$url ='articles/'.$url;
}  else {
$url = 'articles/'.$slug;

}

$posts = posts::where('post_status', '')->get();
if ( empty($slug) ) {
$post = $posts->where('url', $url)->first();
}  else {
$post = $posts->where('slug', $slug)->first();
}

if ( empty($post) )
return redirect()->back();


return view('viewpost')->with('post', $post)->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

New version (modified):

```
public function viewpost($url){


  $posts = posts::where('post_status', '');
  $post = $posts->where('url', $url)->orWhere('slug' , $url)->first();


  if ( empty($post) )
return redirect()->back();


return view('viewpost')->with('post', $post)->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

The new modified controller file broke the posts without a slug.

Here is the view file for the Recent Posts which broke:

```
<h3>Recent Posts</h3>
 @foreach($posts as $post)
 <p><a href="{{ URL::to($post->url) }}"><img style="width:100px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></a><br>
     <a href="{{ URL::to($post->url) }}">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}.. 
 </a></p>               
  @endforeach
```

My Routes code:

```
Route::get('articles/{url}', 'postsController@viewpost');
```

My view file code for the posts page which displays all the posts:

```
                    @foreach($post as $post)

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="content">
                        @if(!empty($post->slug))
                            dd(11);
                        <a href="{{'articles/'.$post->slug}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>

                        @else
                        dd(22);
                        <a href="{{($post->url)}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>
                        @endif
                            <img style="padding: 5px; width:100%; height:218px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                   @endforeach
```

Comment: This is somethink odd `@foreach($post as $post)`

Comment: @C2486 - "There is somethink off" doesn't really offer a solution.

Comment: Did you tried woth like `@foreach($post as $p)`

Comment: $p isn't even mentioned or defined in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) the Recent Posts function in my view file (for the single post page) no longer shows posts.

That's because unlike your old code, you're not retrieving the data:

```
$posts = posts::where('post_status', '');
```

This will only return your query Builder object, so to get those posts, you need to add ->get(); to get the collection, so the code becomes:

```
$posts = posts::where('post_status', '')->get();
```

After that you can filter the one post your looking for via (->first()), by filtring the collection, as it doesn't support the orWhere method (or just use two where() as you did in the old code):

```
$post = $posts->filter(function($object, $key) use ($url) {
     return !strcmp($object->url, 'articles/'.$url) or !strcmp($object->slug, $url);
})->first();
```

Also correct that:

```
@foreach($post as $post)
```

> 2) On the articles page which shows all of the posts, the posts with no slug do not work. when I click on the post, it redirects to /articles. Only posts with a slug work.

I'm not sure but what i saw in your code, and basing on the old method you showed above, I think you have a problem here:

```
<a href="{{'articles/'.$post->slug}}" ...
<a href="{{($post->url)}}" ...
```

doesn't the second one needs also to be (?):

```
<a href="{{'articles/'.$post->url}}" ...
```

Comment: For #2, the two a hrefs code are different because of how it is setup in the database.  The slug is inputted into the database as "custom-post-name".  A url is inputted into the database as "articles/generated-url-here".  A post will only display if "articles/" is in the URL.

Comment: The Recent Post section works now.  But on my articles page (https://collegeconnect.ph/articles), if you click on the second article on the top row (it is uses a url, no slug), you get redirected back to the article page not to the post itself.  Click on the first article (it uses a slug) and you get directed to the post.

Comment: If the Url is insert into DB as "articles/generated-url-here", the the query you've set will never found it. Then you should add 'articles' string to the url got from the request. Cause according to what you say, the code above will look for "generated-url-here" instead of "articles/generated-url-here", I'll edit the filter part of the answer to show you

Comment: Now the problem is that the URL for the post using the slug is different under Recent Posts.  Go to https://collegeconnect.ph/articles, click on the first post in the first row, then look at the URL of that same post in the Recent Posts section.

Comment: That's because in this section you're using the $post->url instead of the slug

Comment: Yep, I just put in the same if else loop and it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the causing factor:

```
return view('viewpost')->with('post', $post)->with('posts', $posts);
```

and your loop is doing:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
```

and your other loop is doing:

```
@foreach($post as $post)
```

If you look at your `with` you are passing both `post` and `posts`, as a result it is probably mixing the looped variable with the `with` variable.

Try and change the keys of the variables in the `with` to something more distinct. You could add an `_` before the single `$post` variable.

Comment: There was no problem with the views code before.  It only broke when the code in the controller file was modified.